# Attempted to add noncontiguous index to GraphQLSegment

Tags: graphql, relayjs, relay

This is the specific log I'm getting:

```
Attempted to add an ID already in GraphQLSegment: client:client:-1453876448127:QXNzZXQ6MTkwMTM5NzYtNjdjZS00ZDlhLTg4OWMtMWYwMzdiNjFmMjVl
stem.js:51568 Attempted to add noncontiguous index to GraphQLSegment: 9 to (0, 7)
```

My query returns a list of items and this error appears when I change the order of the list that gets returned when I make a second request. This causes only a portion of the items to be displayed. Is it possible to reset the Relay Store programmatically?

Comment: Your scenario is not clear. How do you make the second request?